# HTML5 enumerated types

Tags: html

Please, I don't understand this paragraphs from the [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#enumerated-attribute):

> When the attribute is specified, if its value is an ASCII
>   case-insensitive match for one of the given keywords then that
>   keyword's state is the state that the attribute represents. If the
>   attribute value matches none of the given keywords, but the attribute
>   has an invalid value default, then the attribute represents that
>   state. Otherwise, if the attribute value matches none of the keywords
>   but there is a missing value default state defined, then that is the
>   state represented by the attribute. Otherwise, there is no default,
>   and invalid values must be ignored.
>
> When the attribute is not specified, if there is a missing value
>   default state defined, then that is the state represented by the
>   (missing) attribute. Otherwise, the absence of the attribute means
>   that there is no state represented.

in relation to **invalid value default** and **missing value default** words.

Can anyone give me an example or explain better?

Thanks.

Comment: [Close - Move to Programmers Exchange]

Answer (score 2):

An enumerated attribute can defined as having a list of valid values: e.g.

- text
- date
- address
- phone

and also two defaults

- an invalid default e.g. phone
- a missing value default: e.g. text

Then for an element `foo` and attribute `bar` as above:

```
<foo bar="date">   => valid value, state is `date`
<foo bar="time">   => invalid value, state is the invalid default `phone`
<foo>              => missing value, state is the missing value default `text`
```

Sometimes however, the attribute doesn't have an invalid default defined for it, but it does have a missing value default defined. In this case:

```
<foo bar="date">   => valid value, state is `date`
<foo bar="time">   => invalid value, state is the missing value default `text`
<foo>              => missing value, state is the missing value default `text`
```

Sometimes the attribute has an invalid default defined for it, but it doesn't have a missing value default defined. In this case:

```
<foo bar="date">   => valid value, state is `date`
<foo bar="time">   => invalid value, state is the invalid default `phone`
<foo>              => missing value, attribute has no state
```

And sometimes the attribute doesn't have either an invalid default or a missing value default defined for it. In this case:

```
<foo bar="date">   => valid value, state is `date`
<foo bar="time">   => invalid value, attribute has no state
<foo>              => missing value, attribute has no state
```

Comment: What about `<foo bar>`? Is that valid?

Comment: @TimDown - For an enumerated attribute `bar`, it would be treated the same way as `bar="time"` above.

Comment: Is it valid? I can't find a definitive answer in the HTML5 spec. The [section on enumerated attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#enumerated-attribute) isn't explicit. The [section on attribute syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) doesn't mention any restriction on the types of attribute that may have no value, just that no value implies the empty string. On the other hand, [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#contenteditable) says that a value is required for the enumerated attribute `contenteditable`.

Comment: From the first link you give, it says "If an enumerated attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of the given keywords that are not said to be non-conforming, with no leading or trailing whitespace." Note that it must be talking about a content attribute at this point, so the value cannot be a match for one of the given keywords, therefore it must be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It means when the user agent encounters a invalid keyword for a given attribute:

1. if there is a "invalid default" value defined in the spec, then the attribute is treated as in such state.
2. if not, no state is defined for the given attribute.

Where did you see the spec reference this paragraph? If you point it to me I would use that as example.

Comment: click the link on the standard word or go to http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#enumerated-attribute